# In an Android program with two timers, I get an odd bug with one but not the other - the code seems to be the same

Tags: java, android

I have an application which has two timers which should run independently of each other. I had one timer on it's own working correctly, however when I added the second I started getting an odd error.

The application is intended to work so that if you press the Start button next to the Jammer timer, it will begin counting down; and if you press the Start button next to the Blocker 1 timer, it will begin counting down.

However, what happens is if you press the button next to the Jammer timer, it will display 0. If you press the same button again, the Blocker 1 timer will begin counting down correctly. (The reverse does not happen if the button next to Blocker 1 is pressed twice)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.buttonStartJammer:
        toggleTimer(0); 
        break; 

    case R.id.buttonStartBlocker1: 
        toggleTimer(1); 
        break; 
    }

}

private void toggleTimer(final int timer){
    switch(timer){
    case 0: 
    {
        if (jammerTimerRunning) {
        jammerTimer.cancel(); 
        bStartJammer.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.start));
        } else if (jammerTimerDone){
            //stuff
        } else {
        jammerTimer = newTimer(jammerSeconds, 0); 
        jammerTimer.start(); 
        jammerTimerRunning = true;
        break; 
        }
    }
    case 1:
        if(blocker1TimerRunning){
            blocker1Timer.cancel();
            bStartBlocker1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.start)); 
        } else if (blocker1TimerDone) {
            //stuff
        } else {
            blocker1Timer = newTimer(blocker1Seconds, 1);
            blocker1Timer.start(); 
            blocker1TimerRunning = true; 
            break; 
        }
    }

private CountDownTimer newTimer(long seconds, final int timer) {
    long milliseconds = seconds * 1000; 
    return new CountDownTimer(milliseconds,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            switch(timer){
            case 0:
            {
                jammerTimerRunning = false;
                jammerTimerDone = true; 
                tvJammerTimer.setText(String.format("%d",0));
                jammerSeconds = 59; 
                break; 
            }
            case 1: 
            {
                blocker1TimerRunning = false; 
                blocker1TimerDone = true; 
                tvBlocker1Timer.setText(String.format("%d",0)); 
                blocker1Seconds = 59; 
                break; 
            }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            switch(timer){ 
            case 0: 
            {
                jammerSeconds = (millisUntilFinished/1000); 
                tvJammerTimer.setText(String.format("%d",jammerSeconds));
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                blocker1Seconds = (millisUntilFinished/1000);
                tvBlocker1Timer.setText(String.format("%d",blocker1Seconds)); 
                break; 
            }
            }       
        }


    };
}
```

If anyone has any idea what may be causing this it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: I am suspicious of the newTimer method. I'd consider creating separate timers instead of switching between both inside a single timer. That may not be the issue, though. Plus I'm just generally suspicious of anything I write ;)

Comment: I will try that, thanks again for taking the time out to help - I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. I altered the program to have entirely different methods for each timer as Dave suggested, instead of the switch statements, however this had no effect.

I decided to add in blocker2 (with the same methods etc.) to see if this had an effect - and the effect was that the Jammer and Blocker1 timers both set themselves to 0 immediately while blocker2 worked. I noted that this was the text which would be set onFinish of the CountDownTimer, and upon testing this by changing the text, found this to be the case.

I eventually discovered that the problem was in fact that I had initialized several variables incorrectly by mistake.

I had declared several variable in the format -

```
private boolean variable1, variable2, variable3 = false;
```

This meant that only variable3 was set to the correct value.

What I had intended to do was set them in the format -

```
private boolean variable1 = variable2 = variable3 = false;
```

as in C++, however I got an error when I tried to do this in Java (which I am less familiar with) so I settled for declaring them as -

```
private boolean variable1 = false;
private boolean variable2 = false;
private boolean variable3 = false;
```

It is now working as intended :)